# In Lightning But Setup Pages In Classic View

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, salesforce-classic, classic

We are in the process of transitioning from Classic to Lightning. We have enabled Lightning Experience but most pages (Field Details, Apex classes, Deliverability, etc.) under setup are displaying classic view. How can I get all these pages to display with the Lightning touch? Is there a setting?

[image: Field Details]

[image: Deliverability Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Not all Setup pages have been converted to Lightning yet. You're not doing anything wrong, it's just a product limitation. Presumably, those pages will be updated in a future release.

Comment: If I log into any other org, example a playground, the pages mentioned above are not in classic view. By any chance, would you know why there's a difference?

Comment: @Robert There might be a setting around there somewhere. I know that mine looks like classic, but I couldn't say why.